# Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.6:war

Tags: eclipse, maven, installation

[image]I am new to maven project,i had downloaded opensource maven project and try to run it but it gives following errors while maven-install.till now i am not configured database so is this errors are due to database or not please help,i am using jdk 7 and maven 3.3 and eclipse maven integration tool.

Comment: The error says something like "IOException when zipping". What is the rest ?

Comment: Please do not post text as an image! Also, post your pom.